# how can I swap out all non numeric characters to currency format

Tags: php, character, currency, swap, numeric

I need somebody help, I Would be appreciate it and many thanks

Below as several samples that left side i want to swap to currency format/right side

- 123,00        to 123.00
- 1.123,00€     to 1,123.00
- $11.123,00    to 11,123.00
- 12.123,00 ZH  to 12,123.00
- 12.123,00cH   to 12,123.00
- £1.123.123,00 to 1,123,123.00
- 112312300 KN  to 1,123,123.00

or e.g.

- 1,123.00€       to 1,123.00
- $11.123.00      to 11,123.00
- 12,123,00 ZH    to 12,123.00
- 12.123,00cH     to 12,123.00
- £1.123,123,00   to 1,123,123.00
- 11,231230.0 KN  to 1,123,123.00

that mean whatever in left side it should be change to comma as thousand digit and dot as decimal digit,

it seem could be done using **preg_replace** or **str_replace**, but what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Srip out non-numeric characters, and then pass through `number_format()`.

```
$val = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", "11,231230.0 KN") / 100;
$formatted = number_format($val, 2, ".", ",");

// Outputs 1,123,123.00
```

**EDIT** added `/ 100` since it was adding the decimal places after the original zeros.

Comment: hey, I wish I had thought of that :)  To add something useful to this comment, the last two arguments of `number_format` aren't necessary in this case, since the default is the american format (`.` decimal separator, `,` thousands separator).

Comment: Thank you for this code, would also like to add/point out that the /100 doesn't work if there's no decimal place in the original number.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to first remove everything non-numeric and then use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
// assuming $str holds the original string
$str = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $str);  // now just a string of numbers
$str = number_format( $str, 2 ); // 2 decimal places
```

Comment: Oof. I'm Sorry - I edited your post instead of my own.  Undid it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
print number_format(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $number), 2, '.', ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do the same from currency to normalize the format for a project i'm working on.

The code is reworking any string to output if formatted as `#####.##` and support these inputs :

```
// these are my unit test check
0.00 returned by filtering 0
0.20 returned by filtering 0.2
0.20 returned by filtering 0,2
0.22 returned by filtering 0.22
0.22 returned by filtering 0,22
18.20 returned by filtering 18.2
1000.00 returned by filtering 1 000
1000.00 returned by filtering 1,000
1000.00 returned by filtering 1,000.00
1000.00 returned by filtering 1000,00
1000.00 returned by filtering 1 000,00
1000.20 returned by filtering 1 000,2
1000.20 returned by filtering 1 000,20 $
1000.20 returned by filtering abc1def00test0dot.twenty20
```

and any other combination interlace with any non numeric chars

```
    if (strpos($string, '.') === false
        && strpos($string, ',') === false
    ) {
        $string .= '.00';
    }

    $string = preg_replace('/[^0-9.,]/', '', $string);

    $string = preg_replace('/[.,]/', '.', $string);

    while (
        strpos($string, '.') != strrpos($string, '.')
        || strlen($string) - 1 - strrpos($string, '.') > 2
    ) {
        $pos = strpos($string, '.');
        if ($pos > 0) {
            $string = substr($string, 0, $pos) . substr($string, $pos +1);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return (float)$string;
```

And finally use `number_format()` to reformat the standardized number